# WebDriver: How to automate Input masked birthday ( / / ) field

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am finding difficulty in automating input masked field, sendKeys is what I have tried.

```html
<li class="required fly-group">
<input id="patient_birthday" class="required-field date-masked" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Birthday" name="patient[birthday]"/>
<div class="small weak">mm/dd/yyyy</div>
</li>
```

After I provide input (12/12/1990) using sendKeys and run the script, this field is left blank and webdriver proceeds with next field.

Comment: Have you found a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

It is about python script?
Also, can you post code.

I am thinking simply - in python this should works

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('patient_birthday')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys('12/12/1990')
```

In any case, try to check if you have got "input" block and you can input anything in it (at least one figure) or modify it.

Comment: Script is in Java:       driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='patient_birthday']")).isDisplayed();                                                                                            
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='patient_birthday']")).sendKeys("12/12/1990");

Comment: I do not know Java, but my advice based on experience with selenium on python - try to use driver.findElement(By.id("patient_birthday")). And additionally i retrieve from google next function SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy "); Here you can read examples http://learn-automation.com/how-to-get-current-system-date-and-time-in-java-selenium/